# Controlling user input in regards to strings in bidimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to allow the user to only write names of students in uppercase in C.

I've tried :

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int number_ofstudents, i, j;
    char Name[100][20];

    do {
        printf("Enter number of students \n");
        scanf("%i", &number_ofstudents);
    } while ((number_ofstudents < 0) || (number_ofstudents > 100));

    for (i = 0; i < number_ofstudents; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= strlen(Name[i]) - 1; j++) {
            printf("Enter the name of student number %i in uppercase  \n", i + 1);

            do {
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(Name[i], 20, stdin);
            } while ((Name[i][j] < 'A') || (Name[i][j] > 'Z'));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried:

```c
 for (i = 0; i < number_ofstudents; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= Name[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
        printf("Enter the name of student number %i in uppercase  \n", i + 1);
        do {
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(Name[i], 20, stdin);
        } while ((Name[i][j] < 'A') || (Name[i][j] > 'Z'));
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting is for the program to keep demanding that I enter the name of the student number x until my input is all in uppercase, however once I execute none of my inputs are accepted and the phrase "Enter the name of student number 1 in uppercase " keeps repeating itself.

Does the issue lie in my  2nd for loop when I'm trying to manipulate the letter input? I haven't learned pointers or functions yet.

Comment: These for loops  for (i=0; i<number_ofstudents; i++) { 
for (j=0; j<=strlen(Name[i])-1; j++){ do not make sense. You have uninitialized array Name.

Comment: The call fflush(stdin); has undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i didn't initialize it because the user himself is going to fill the array with strings.